# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}\log(x) - \log(1- x)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I have a function $\log(x) - \log(1- x)$,

and I wish to evaluate the limit as $x \to \infty$. I thought this was just $\infty$ since the limit as $x \to \infty$ of each term is $\infty$, but Mathematica somehow is returning $i \pi$ when I tried it. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: $\log(1-x)$ is not defined (except in complex sense) when $x>1$. That explains the Mathematica result. Because the "limit" is $\log(-1) = i\pi$

Comment: The domain of your function is the open interval $(0,1)$. There is no meaning in considering $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Might you have meant $\log x - \log(x-1)\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @GautamShenoy Even then, Mathematica should be using principal branches, which would result in $-\pi i$.

Comment: `Mathematica 11.1` and `Maple 2017.2` give me: $ - i \pi$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk :D Glad to know then, mind mentioning it in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. I am using Mathematica 10.

Comment: Did you get something like this? $$\texttt{Mathematica 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)}$$ $$\texttt{
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.}$$
$$\texttt{In[1]:= Limit[Log[x] - Log[1 - x], x -> Infinity]}$$
$$\texttt{Out[1]= -I Pi}$$

Answer (score 7):

With some algebra,$$\log x - \log(1 - x) = \log \frac{x}{1 - x} \to \log(-1)$$

which Mathematica interprets as $i\pi$, and you can too if you choose that particular branch of the complex logarithm. It's a natural choice because $e^{i\pi} = -1$.

---

On a different but important note, however, the reasoning

> I thought this was just $\infty$ since the limit as $x \to \infty$ of each term is $\infty$

is unfortunately *very* mistaken. For example, $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x - x) = 0$, but each term obviously goes to infinity.

Comment: But, I don't understand:  Spivak Theorem 5.2: $\lim_{x \to a} (f + g)(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f + \lim_{x \to a} g$

Comment: This assumes that both limits exist and are finite.

Comment: When the limits are both real numbers, this is true. (And if they are the *same* signed infinity, this is true too). But when the first limit is $+\infty$ and the second is $-\infty$, there is a real problem. Check out [indeterminate forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: @ThomasMoore Yes, that is correct, assuming both limits exist and are finite. $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to hazard a guess that what was meant was $\log x - \log(x-1).$

One can write $\log x - \log(x-1) = \log \dfrac x {x-1}$ and then

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \log\frac x {x-1} & = \log \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac x {x-1} \quad \text{because log is continuous} \\[10pt]
& = \log 1 =0.
\end{align}

Or one can say that by the mean value theorem there exists $c_x$ between $x-1$ and $x$ for which
$$
\log x - \log(x-1) = \log' c_x = \frac 1 {c_x} < \frac 1 {x-1} \to 0 \text{ as } x\to\infty.
$$

Comment: Isn't $\ln c_x = \frac{d(c_x)}{c_x dx}$ using chain rule?

Comment: @user263326 : No. $\dfrac d {dx} \ln c_x$ would indeed be equal to $\dfrac 1 {c_x} \cdot \dfrac d {dx} c_x,$ provided $c_x$ is a differentiable function of $x.$ But that's $\dfrac d{dx} \ln c_x,$ not $\ln c_x$ without $\text{“} \dfrac d{dx}\text{''}.$ But your comment is irrelevant: I never sought $\dfrac d{dx} \ln c_x.$ The expression $\log' c_x$ is NOT the same thing as $\dfrac d{dx} \log c_x$ and was not intended to be the same thing. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming principal branches, Mathematica is actually wrong. Note that the identity

$$\log(a)-\log(b)=\log(a/b)$$

holds for $a,b\in\Bbb R_{>0}$, but not generally for any other $a,b$. Using principle branches and assuming $x>1$, we actually have

$$\log(1-x)=\log|1-x|+i\arg(1-x)=\log(x-1)+\pi i$$

hence,

\begin{align}\log(x)-\log(1-x)&=\log(x)-\log(x-1)-\pi i\\&=\log\left(\frac x{x-1}\right)-\pi i\\&\to\log(1)-\pi i\\&=-\pi i\\&\ne\pi i\end{align}

---

Note that Mathematica 11.1 returns $-\pi i$.

Comment: Unless someone who uses Mathematica knows what sort of branch it uses is not the principal branch? Would be nice to know...

Comment: It's also possible that Mathematica was not wrong, but instead Mathematica's answer was misreported. Has the $\pi i$ answer been confirmed by someone other than the OP? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+log(x)%E2%88%92log(1%E2%88%92x)+as+x-%3Einfinity gives $-\pi i$.

Comment: @LarsH Possibly. Unfortunately, we don't know what version the OP was using.